# lisp last element functional form

Tags: lisp

Hey guys I need help with lisp function. I am supposed to create:

(myLast L)
    Evaluates to the last element of list L.
    eg.  (myLast ‘(p a e g))  →  g

I cant use all of the predefined forms for lisp only the ones we have been given in class:

```
(atom X)
(quote X)
‘X
(eq X Y)
(cons X L)
(car L)
(cdr L)
(list A B C)
(if X Y Z)      
(cond (C1 S1) (C2 S2) …… (Cn Sn))
```

I thought I had it right when I put in:

```
(defun myLast (L)
   (if ((eq L '()) (cdr L))
      (car L)
      (myLast (cdr L))))
```

However I am getting an error:

```
Error: The variable MYHW4.LISP is unbound.
Error signalled by EVAL
Backtrace: EVAL
Broken at SYSTEM::GCL-TOP-LEVEL.
```

I am completely new to LISP and trying to complete this assignment. I was hoping you guys could help me out and let me know why I am getting this error, and is my logic for the last functional form correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.

You have excess parentheses. `((eq L '())` is not allowed as the only expression allowed at operator position is an anonymous function.

Your `if` only have a consequence expression but not a alternative. It isn't the last expression so it's dead code.

The you do `car`, also not in real position so far code also.

Tail expression is the recursion and is done unconditionally. It's called infinite recursion.

I think perhaps you meant something like this:

```
(defun myLast (list)
  (if (null (cdr list)) 
      (car list) 
      (myLast (cdr list))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is unrelated to your code. You probably typed `(load myhw4.lisp)` without quotes in which case your Lisp rightly think that you wanted to take the value bound to the variable `myhw4.lisp`, which does not exist. You need to quote strings `"like so"`.

Also, `((eq L '()) ...)` is problematic, since the first form is `(eq ...)` which is not a function or a lambda. That will signal an error..

The above makes your code wrong, but you are not far from it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found out what I was doing wrong while trying to load it.

Comment: (defun myLast (L)
           (if (lambda (eq L '()) (cdr L))
           (car L)
           (myLast (cdr L))))

This is what I have changed it to but something is off I am getting the first item of the list instead of the last. Any suggestions?

Comment: Or simply `(if (eq (cdr L) ()) (car L) (my-last (cdr L)))`. I am surprised your Lisp did not reject the argument list of your `lambda`. Plus, if you only test (if (lambda ...) x y) then the test is always T, since an anonymous function, being not the symbol NIL, evaluates as true in a boolean context. So you would always take the first element. A little more testing might help.